# How to change a list of list to a dictionary of dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

So for example I have the following list of lists

```
 A = [['PokedexNumber',  'Name',  'Type',  'Total'], [1.0, 'Bulbasaur', 'GrassPoison', 318.0], [2.0, 'Ivysaur', 'GrassPoison', 405.0],[3.0, 'Venusaur', 'GrassPoison', 525.0]]
```

How do i change it to dictionary of dictionaries?

```
B = { 1.0 : { 'Name' : 'Bulbasaur', 'Type' : 'GrassPoison', 'Total' : 318.0},

      2.0 : {'Name' : 'Ivysaur', 'Type' : 'GrassPoison', 'Total' : 405.0},

      3.0 : {'Name' : 'Venusaur', 'Type' : 'GrassPoison', 'Total' : 525.0}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a dictionary comprehension with slicing that should do the trick:

```
A = [['PokedexNumber', 'Name', 'Type', 'Total'], [1.0, 'Bulbasaur', 'GrassPoison', 318.0], [2.0, 'Ivysaur', 'GrassPoison', 405.0],[3.0, 'Venusaur', 'GrassPoison', 525.0]]

B = {x[0]: dict(zip(A[0][1:], x[1:])) for x in A[1:]}

print(B)
```

Output:

```
{
   1.0: {'Name': 'Bulbasaur', 'Type': 'GrassPoison', 'Total': 318.0}, 
   2.0: {'Name': 'Ivysaur', 'Type': 'GrassPoison', 'Total': 405.0}, 
   3.0: {'Name': 'Venusaur', 'Type': 'GrassPoison', 'Total': 525.0}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use sequence unpacking and a dictionary comprehension:

```
(_, *headers), *data = A

res = {num: dict(zip(headers, values)) for num, *values in data}
```

Result:

```
{1.0: {'Name': 'Bulbasaur', 'Type': 'GrassPoison', 'Total': 318.0},
 2.0: {'Name': 'Ivysaur', 'Type': 'GrassPoison', 'Total': 405.0},
 3.0: {'Name': 'Venusaur', 'Type': 'GrassPoison', 'Total': 525.0}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> A = [['PokedexNumber',  'Name',  'Type',  'Total'], [1.0, 'Bulbasaur', 'GrassPoison', 318.0], [2.0, 'Ivysaur', 'GrassPoison', 405.0],[3.0, 'Venusaur', 'GrassPoison', 525.0]]
>>> B = {}
>>> for p in A[1:]:
...    B[p[0]] = { 'name': p[1], 'type': p[2], 'total': p[3] }
...
>>> B
{1.0: {'total': 318.0, 'type': 'GrassPoison', 'name': 'Bulbasaur'}, 2.0: {'total': 405.0, 'type': 'GrassPoison', 'name': 'Ivysaur'}, 3.0: {'total': 525.0, 'type': 'GrassPoison', 'name': 'Venusaur'}}

>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to use a 3rd party library, you can use Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

headers, *data = A

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)
B = df.set_index('PokedexNumber').to_dict('index')
```

Result:

```
{1.0: {'Name': 'Bulbasaur', 'Type': 'GrassPoison', 'Total': 318.0},
 2.0: {'Name': 'Ivysaur', 'Type': 'GrassPoison', 'Total': 405.0},
 3.0: {'Name': 'Venusaur', 'Type': 'GrassPoison', 'Total': 525.0}}
```